# How can I get the full hex string of a blob via SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, blob, ssms

If I have a blob in the database and I select it, I get the following result:

```
Blob
------
0xABCDEF1234567890...
```

What query can I perform, or what options can I set that will retrieve the full hexadecimal string so that I can copy and paste it out of SSMS?

I want the string exactly as it's displayed in the grid view, in hexadecimal format, it just truncates it.

I am aware that you can export the data, generate a file, or hook up a .NET CLR and retrieve the data that way, but for the sake of this question, the process must work when connected to a remote database, AND must only use SSMS features. No exports, no files, just a result in SSMS (e.g. "0x12345...") that is copy and pasteable.

Comment: Could you use Linqpad instead or another SSMS alternative without result limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. If you look at the advanced options (Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid), the largest option for non-XML data is 65535 bytes.

Maybe you could cast it as XML and remove the mark up.

Comment: Most of our blobs are under 65k, so this actually looks like it'll work. Failing that, I may give the XML a try. For anyone else that wants to know: It still displays the info truncated, BUT when you copy (Ctrl+C) the grid cell with your blob data in it, the full data gets copied (up to 65535 bytes). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you go into to Tools -> Options menu on SSMS, and under the Query Results -> SQL Server section you can change the maximum number of characters to return under the "Results to Grid" and "Results to Text" sections.